# What is an example of a runtime verification tool being used to audit a smart contract?

Tags: formal-verification, audit

[Runtime Verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_verification) i a computing system analysis and execution approach based on extracting information from a running system and using it to detect and possibly react to observed behaviors satisfying or violating certain properties, and it has been used to help secure smart contracts.

What is a minimal example of using runtime verification to audit a smart contract?